# MS-Access, Days between two dates rolling, based on a value

Tags: ms-access-2010

looking for help regarding calculation between 2 dates on a rolling basis with a value criteria.

My table is called

> ODB_AC_PN_TRANSACTION_HISTORY

and set as below in the first 3 columns. The last column is what I am seeking.

I want to know the number of days between a date and the previous occuring date for the records based on the value in the PN column

```
TRANSACTION (unique key)    PN              TRANSACTION_DATE    Days
16/07/0312:53:02:04800      02A0016-32      15/07/2003          0
5/08/200314:47:53:5960      002A0016-32     1/08/2003           17
9/09/200315:06:50:0550      002A0016-32     29/08/2003          28
18/10/0315:02:08:4540       002A0016-32     23/09/2003          25
25/11/0309:38:41:7440       002A0016-32     21/11/2003          59
18/12/0314:14:39:3560       002A0016-32     12/12/2003          21
19/09/200713:40:39:8870     0050N1          14/08/2007          0
15/10/200714:49:39:3590     0050N1          20/09/2007          37
13/11/200710:39:57:1200     0050N1          17/10/2007          27
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your Transaction field doesn't have the same format for date in all rows. Is that correct?

Comment: And is your P/N supposed to be a match in forst two rows even though the first row is missing a leading 0?

Comment: Yes the transaction field isn't the same date format, it is a mixture of date, time and some other arbitrary number. The first 2 numbers are supposed to be the same as well, will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be a query like this:

```
SELECT
    TRANSACTION,
    PN,
    TRANSACTION_DATE,
        -DateDiff("d", TRANSACTION_DATE, 
            (Select Max(T.TRANSACTION_DATE) As PreviousDate
            From ODB_AC_PN_TRANSACTION_HISTORY As T
            Where 
                T.TRANSACTION_DATE < ODB_AC_PN_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.TRANSACTION_DATE
                And
                T.PN = ODB_AC_PN_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.PN)) As
    Days
FROM
    ODB_AC_PN_TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
ORDER BY
    PN Asc,
    TRANSACTION_DATE Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you had a typo in P/N - and that your date format was based on your system formatting. If it doesn't sort in the correct order, you'll need some parsing of year/month/day and then use DateSerial function

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateTransactionDays()

    Dim rs                      As DAO.Recordset

    Dim strTransactionDate      As String
    Dim lngNumDays              As Long

    Dim strSQL                  As String
    Dim strLastPN               As String
    Dim strLastDate             As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM InputTableName ORDER BY PN, TRANSACTION_DATE"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            strTransactionDate = ![Transaction_Date]

            If strLastPN = !PN Then
                lngNumDays = DateDiff("d", strLastDate, strTransactionDate)
            Else
                ' First occurence
                lngNumDays = 0
            End If
            Debug.Print lngNumDays

            ' Update Num Days since last transaction
            .Edit
            ![Days] = lngNumDays
            .Update

            strLastDate = strTransactionDate
            strLastPN = !PN
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```